# create dynamic dataset in R

Tags: r, sas, macros

I am trying to convert my following SAS script to R script:

```
%macro CDF(time=,Type= );
    
                data temp_&Type._&time.;
                set F1_&Type._&time.;
                if Flag="TRUE";
                run;
    %mend CDF;
    
    %CDF(time= Hour,Type=Test)
```

I am trying to convert this block to R. But while in R, if I use paste0() to create a data frame, I am not getting expected result.

```
CDF <- function(time=,Type=){
    if (paste0("f1_", Type, "_", time,"$Flag") == "TRUE"){
        paste0("temp_", Type, "_", time) <- paste0("f1_", Type, "_", time)
      }
}
```

**Note-** Column Flag is having TRUE/FALSE values.

Please suggest me a way to create and assign a data frame dynamically.

Comment: The left-hand side of an assignment needs to be a name or a subset expression. You can’t assign to the result of `paste`. The proper way to solve this is to *return* the newly generated object. There are more issues with your code, for instance, where is `Flag` defined? As a *general* rule it’s a bad idea to try to convert code between different languages directly while ignoring language specifics. Yes, you *can* create a verbatim copy of the SAS code in R, but it’s *bad code*. R has better ways of expressing this.

Comment: I have a database table  name f1_Test_Hour which contains a column Flag. with TRUE/FALSE values.

Comment: R dislikes macros and dislikes void functions with border effects. We can tell you what you how you can do what you want to do but be warned this is not idiomatic at all in the R language. You shouldn't "translate" SAS language word by word, or you will be disappointed as in a google translation

Comment: @Ankit OK, the first step then would be to reformat your data: instead of having multiple tables `f1_‹Test›_‹Hour›`, in R you’d use a *single* table, `f1`, with columns for the test and the hour. Alternatively you could use a nested list of tables, but (without knowing your specific use-case) a single master table would be the default solution in R, and is appropriate in most situations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but I have multiple such tables basis on the time/Type parameter. this is why I need a solution to make it dynamic. For a single or small number of tables,  I can assign the values using list of dataframes.

Comment: @Ankit OK but *why* do you have them in separate tables? As noted, this simply isn’t a good data model (in R, but also more generally!). If that’s how the data is delivered to you (in separate files, say), your first order of business would be to merge the data. There should *never* be separate tables of this form in your R code; if there are, that’s already wrong.